# Bring unique entries in multiple columns as new columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['W1','W1','W2','W2','W3'],[1,2,3,4,5],['A','A','B','B','B'],['R','D','D','R','D']],index=['Week','ID','V1','V2']).transpose()
```

I want to create a new dataframe:

1. The unique values in column V1 and V2 will be new columns
2. The values under these new columns will be count of ID falling under corresponding week

The output will look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Week':['W1','W2','W3'],'A':[2,0,0],
               'B':[0,2,1],
               'D':[1,1,1],
               'R':[1,1,0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
res = df.set_index(['Week', 'ID']).stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index(name='V1_V2')
out = pd.crosstab(res['Week'], res['V1_V2'])
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
V1_V2  A  B  D  R
Week             
W1     2  0  1  1
W2     0  2  1  1
W3     0  1  1  0
```